# Minor changes in ASPX depending on User/Client

Tags: c#, .net

I have two different user/clients accessing a page that provides a feature. The two users will see a slightly different page. I.e. The api calls from that page will differ and message on some buttons will be different too.

What's the best way to do this?
I'm thinking about having a config in the database that the aspx uses to load differently.
Or making another aspx file.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in different ways. I can give you a couple of ways.

- You can pass a model from the controller which contains API URL,
  message, and other stuff for specific users.
- You can pass the message and other stuff via ViewBag from the controller to view.